# Google bans Huawei. What should I do with google dependencies?

Tags: publish, progressive-web-apps, huawei-mobile-services, twa

I have a few apps on Play Market and I'd like to publish them on Huawei AppGallery. I care about next dependencies:

- com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs
- play-services-ads
- firebase-core

Am I right that no one from this list will work? I mean on devices in ban list.
If yes what are workarounds for that dependencies? Or any other/additional restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For google releated dependencies you have to use huawei provided [services](https://developer.huawei.com/en/) or third party SDK. 
It's not so much hard to convert them. You can use [HMS Core Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/05673260), it help you to quickly migrate the app to the HMS to release it in the HUAWEI AppGallery.

1. Firebase Authentication: Integrate [HMS Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-accountkit), Integrate AGC Auth Service
2. Fire Base: HMS [Push kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit).
3. Firebase Crashlytics: [AGC Crash Service.](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-crash-introduction)
4. Firebase A/B Testing:  Huawei A/B Testing
5. play-services-ads: Huawe [ADS kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit).

Comment: Yes, now Huawei has provided almost all common services. 9 months ago it was a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As is known, new Huawei devices don't have GMS, like Mate 30 and P40. Huawei has built up an HMS ecosystem to make apps available to improve user experience on these devices. It's recommended that you use GMS if a device supports GMS; otherwise, use HMS (Huawei Mobile Services).
As for dependencies:

1. play-services-ads: It is recommended that you use [HUAWEI Ads Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit.).
2. firebase-core: You can use HMS Core instead.

One more thing, here is the [overview of HMS](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms).

Answer (score 1):

You can use productflavors to build two seperate version of your application, one with pure GMS one with pure HMS.

Here is a guide about how you can achieve that: 
https://medium.com/huawei-mobile-developers/guide-to-implement-mobile-services-from-different-providers-in-single-codebase-build-variants-b3610fb77fec

And Demo: 
https://github.com/Disav0wed/BuildVariantMapsDemo

Answer (score 0):

The ban actually is from US side, Google is just abiding the guidelines.

You can easily deploy your application in AppGallery using Huawei Mobile Services.
Almost all mandatory services are covered as of today, rich community and developer forum support is also available if you stuck up in development or deployment.

In order to deploy your app you can follow up below steps.
Use HMS Toolkit to identify the dependencies.
Once services are identified you can add them in your application.

Codelabs are available to practice as well.
I would recommend to have  a single codebase and just switch to GMS or HMS depending on device where your app is downloaded.

Most of the major apps are using same functionality now a days.

[Codelab](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/community/codelabs)

[Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/home)

[Official Documentation of services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/account-specification)

I hope this helps you.